# New class based generic views and urlpatterns

Tags: django, django-views

with former generic views, I had something like this

```
link_info_dict = {
    'queryset' : Link.objects.all(),
    'date_field' : 'pub_date',
}
patterns('django.views.generic.date_based',
    url(r'^links/$', 'archive_index', link_info_dict, 'coltrane_link_archive_index'),
....
)
```

Now with new class based generic views, I found that the following seems to work :

```
from django.views.generic.dates import ArchiveIndexView
....
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^links/$', ArchiveIndexView.as_view(**link_info_dict), name='coltrane_link_archive_index'),
....
)
```

I'm wondering if i'm doing things the best way.
Because I have to call the 'as_view' method, I have to import view first, and so I can't "factorize" the "django.views.generic.date_based". I'm actually using nearly all the date_based generic views. Is importing all those views at first and letting the patterns('' empty prefix the right approach ?
If I migrate all my apps to this new style of views, I'd prefer to do things the right way :)

Thanks

Comment: There is a misprint in your urls.py.   Change link_info_dict to entry_info_dict or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

This looks fine - are you sure there isn't something else wrong?  This lines up with the [examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/#django.views.generic.dates.ArchiveIndexView).

```
from django.views.generic.dates import ArchiveIndexView

from myapp.models import Article

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^archive/$',
        ArchiveIndexView.as_view(model=Article, date_field="pub_date"),
        name="article_archive"),
)
```

And it aligns with the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#simple-usage-in-your-urlconf)

> Any arguments passed to as_view() will override attributes set on the class.

Comment: Thank you ! I guess you can pass the model as argument or a queryset... In this case, I use a queryset to be able to change the manager later. It seems to work fine.